# CSS Animation: Curve Arrows

Tags: css

Is it possible to circularly animated this image? [image]

I attempted to animate it by creating a relative parent and setting each image (business solutions div, it solutions div, lifecycle solutions div and education solutions div to absolute). I used  this code, @keyframes rotate {
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
and it rotated in different behavior. They rotated on their own place.

I want to animate it in such a way that: the 4 services will circularly move. Except the outer and inner texts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may rotate the outer container as you stated and rotate the texts into the other direction on the same speed. But it will be a little bit sluggish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of the general pricipal.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}
.object {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: plum;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s infinite reverse linear;
  animation: spin 10s infinite reverse linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="object">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least two elements.  The static one must have have transparent areas so that it can sit over or behind the rotating div.

To rotate the div:

```
div.your-rotating-element {
    animation-name: rotate-div;
    /*enter other styles*/
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    }

@-moz-keyframes rotate-div { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-div { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes rotate-div { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```